# Open with Ubuntu Software Center in kde

Tags: 12.04, software-center, kde, games

I bought the humble bundle pack and how can i open it with Software-center? I normally use Software-center.

[image: 2]

When i click on "Download for ubuntu" i get this ↓
[image: 2]

and when i click on "Launch Application" i get this ↓
[image: 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried opening the Software Center and finding the games you want to install there?

It looks like the only thing that went wrong was that your web browser didn't properly launch the Software Center.

Comment: lol :P don't know why i just tried that.. but thanks :D